# An exposed filter works only with certain taxonomy terms (weird to me)

Tags: 7, views

I have a "commercial property" and "residencial property" node types.
One for offices, cellars, etc and the other to houses, apartments, etc

They share some fields (price, address, etc) and also a field that I called "Kind of property" that is a taxonomy dictionary:

Kind of property:

- Office
- Cellar
- House
- Apartment
- Estate

I have a View that works like a "Property search" and I have exposed the field "Kind of property". I created a menu for each one, so the visitor can go to "Sales - Apartments" and the View will show all the available apartments that are on sale.

This is the example URL for Apartments on sale: [http://www.asir.com.co/inmuebles/buscar?asignacion[]=Venta&field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid=18](http://www.asir.com.co/inmuebles/buscar?asignacion%5b%5d=Venta&field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid=18)

See that "asignacion" is a field that I use to mark the property if it is for sale or for rent (in this case Venta means Sale)

And also see that "field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid" point to the taxonomy term that is on the field "Kind of property".

The issue that I'm having is that *field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid=18* works good, and also *field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid=19* workds good, but if *field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid=**20*** then it dosen't work and the view result is empty. (18 = Apartments, 19 = Houses, 20 = Estates, wich are the taxonomy terms).

I checked the nodes and there are nodes created that are using the termin id 20, but the View is not showing them so don't know how to troubleshoot this, any idea?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: does the view filter by content type, and if so, are Estates of the same content type as apartments and houses?

Comment: I have a "commercial property" and "residencial property" content types and both are included in the View filters. Weird is that Estates are in the "residencial property" content type; houses and apartments as well and those shows without a problem.

Comment: Have you added any relationship, if you have DB access then try to execute the view query manually in the DB.

Comment: Yes, there is a relationship in the View (field_tipo_de_inmueble_tid).

When try to execute the view query in the DB I get error: ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} node LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_tipo_de_inmueble} field_data_field_tipo_de_i' at line 3`

Comment: Found my mistake !!

I rechecked every value on the View filters, and the city filter had a value on it, so I left empty the city and now the property is showing ok, because that property is not on the city that was the default.

Thanks to all for the help and sorry to waste your time.

PS: How do I should to mark this question? Do I have to erase it? post my own solution?

Comment: add what you found out as an answer, and then once permitted, mark it as accepted - that way it doesn't show up as unanswered, but is still available to the community if someone searches for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. I rechecked every value on the View filters, and the city filter had a value on it, so I left empty the city and now the property is showing ok, because that property is not on the city that was the default.